# Why does the Solarized colorscheme look different in vim than it does in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, vim, colors

In iTerm2, the background color looks like this:
[image]

While in Vim, the color looks like this (I'm using https://github.com/altercation/solarized):
[image]

I'd like the first version everywhere. Now, I've never understood terminal colors, but this is my setup:

- `TERM` is set to `xterm-256color` in iTerm2's preferences.
- in my vimrc, I have

  ```
  let g:solarized_termcolors=256
  set t_Co=256
  set bg=dark
  colo solarized
  ```

In MacVim, I see proper colors wothout any adjustment.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to delete `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` since that will tell vim to use degraded colors (see https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users)